# Get unix time from date

Tags: c, date, time

I have the following variables:

```
int year = 2013;
int month = 04;
int day = 07;
int hour = 13;
int min = 42;
int sec = 00;
```

...and I need to extract the "epoch" time, or unix time, from them.

How can this be done in standard C?
In this case, the unix time should be: [1365342120](http://www.epochconverter.com/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The above answer misses some things you might not notice if you've never used this struct:

```
struct tm myTm = {
.tm_sec = sec,
.tm_min = min,
...
.tm_mon= mon-1,
.tm_year= year-1900,

};

time_t t = mktime(&myTm);
printf("%ju\n", (uintmax_t) t);
```

you should subtract 1 to the month, and 1900 to the year or you'll get the wrong answer.

Answer (score 3):

How about:

```
struct tm tm = {
    .tm_sec = sec,
    .tm_min = min,
    ...
};

time_t t = mktime(&tm);
printf("%ju\n", (uintmax_t) t);
```

As Mppl points out, before using this you should be aware of the quirks of `struct tm`:

- `tm_mon` is defined as *months since January*, so you need to subtract 1 from the month
- `tm_year` is defined as *years since 1900*, so you need to subtract 1900 from the year

---

In a more pedantic side-note, nothing guarantees converting t into an integer will automatically give you the number of seconds since 1970. It works on many systems but the standard makes no provision for this.

If you want to go standard-crazy you could make another `time_t` representing `1970` and then do a `difftime` between the two: you'll get the difference as a plain honest `double`.